# Unable to find column with logical name while setting bean property

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, maven, hibernate-mapping

I am not able to start my project this error pop up :

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
> refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'commentRepository' defined in
> com.vivek.discussion.repository.CommentRepository defined in
> @EnableJpaRepositories declared on
> JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot
> resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean
> property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method
> failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to
> find column with logical name: postId in
> org.hibernate.mapping.Table(post) and its related supertables and
> secondary tables

**User.class**

```java
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import java.time.Instant;


@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userId;

    @NotBlank(message = "Username is required")
    private String username;

    @NotBlank(message = "Password is required")
    private String password;

    @Email
    @NotEmpty(message = "Email is required")
    private String email;

    private Instant created;
    private boolean enabled;
}
```

**Post.class**

```java
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.lang.Nullable;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import java.time.Instant;

@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Cannot left this blank")
    private String postName;

    @Nullable
    private String url;

    @Nullable
    @Lob
    private String description;

    private int voteCount;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userid", referencedColumnName = "userid")
    private User user;

    private Instant createdDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Subreddit subreddit;
}
```

**Comment.class**

```java
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import java.time.Instant;

import static javax.persistence.FetchType.LAZY;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty
    private String text;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "postId", referencedColumnName = "postId")
    private Post post;

    private Instant createdDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName = "userId")
    private User user;
}
```

**CommentRepo.class**

```
import com.vivek.discussion.model.Comment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface CommentRepository extends JpaRepository<Comment,Long> {
}
```

**Pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.vivek</groupId>
    <artifactId>discussion</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>discussion</name>
    <description>Application where student can discuss on any topic they want</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Error :**

[image: jpamapping error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reference column name caused the problem in your code,
in comment class the annotation join column should be modified.
Change the referenced column name to id as in the class post you have mentioned it as id.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Comment` class, Change this line:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "postId", referencedColumnName = "postId")
```

To this one

```
@JoinColumn(name = "postId", referencedColumnName = "id")
```